# Is there any way to un-nock arrows?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

When letting go of L2, Aloy un-nocks her loaded arrow. However, if you've unlocked the Double or Triple Shot skills, you are able to load 2 or 3 arrows onto your bow, respectively, by pressing R1. These arrows stay set so that the next time you fire your bow, you'll fire 2 or 3 arrows at once. This is usually helpful, but I just wasted 3 arrows firing at a fox roughly 10 minutes after my last combat encounter, due to having loaded extra arrows during that time.

I'm not sure how to *remove* these arrows so that you'll only fire 1 arrow the next time, once you've loaded a second or third arrow. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't have those skills yet, but does switching weapons or ammo types do it?

Comment: I would agree with @ChrisHayes, possibly switching weapons could do it, but perhaps it's an oversight by the developers...

Comment: @ChrisHayes this fix it, not sure why I didn't think to check. I'll try it when I get home today.

Comment: When I started this game, I jumped down and got triple shot as fast as possible and noticed this as well. What I also noticed was that just switching to a new weapon and then back does not un-nock arrows. What I haven't tried or have not paid attention to is if you switch arrow types of the same bow. You might want to check to see if they un-nock when flipping between the normal arrows and fire arrows or other alternate arrows. You would think that nocking a new arrow type would mean that Aloy would put the others away, but who really knows, maybe technology has advanced far beyond us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked based on the suggestions in the comments. I can confirm that changing arrow types after nocking multiple arrows **will** cause the old type of nocked arrows to be unloaded and the new type to have a single arrow loaded. Switching back to the first type of arrow will cause Aloy to only have a single arrow loaded.

However, interestingly enough, unequipping the bow entirely then re-equipping it will result in the same number of arrows being nocked before and after the fact...

Comment: Did they patch this? I tried a couple of days ago and switching arrow types didn't unnock anything. I had 2 arrows nocked in every type of arrow I owned.

Comment: @ChrisHayes there was a patch a day or two ago, but I'm not sure if that fixed it. When I tried just before posting this, what I said worked for me. I find it odd that unequipping weapons won't un-nock the arrows, though...

Comment: I can confirm what Venomus says - switching weapon & back has no effect, switching ammo type & back for the same weapon works

Comment: I know that I'm late to the party; but I would suggest that this isn't a bug in need of a fix, but rather a feature. Scenario: You are in stealth. There are two machines, one that is weak to flame. Nock 3 flame arrows > switch to ropecaster > tie down the other machine > switch back to your bow and boom, you have three flame arrows ready. 

Seems nifty to me.

(However, I would agree that unequipping your bow should un-nock. That's just silly that it doesn't.)